# remotely check amount of RAM on a computer using command line

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote, memory, windows-command-prompt, windows-xp

How would I remotely check the amount of RAM on a computer using command line? (Windows XP and/or windows server 2003)

Comment: Please clarify: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Assuming a system > Windows 2000  since `cmd` is tagged.

Comment: Although _cmd_ could just be short for _command_ or _command line_, which could be anything.

Comment: windows xp and/or server 2003. I just forgot to post it, I'm so use to working with windows products. Also, I tagged cmd. Thanks Stefan for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requires XP or later system: `wmic memphysical list full`, also `wmic memorychip list full` might provide you with some info you are looking for.

Comment: +1 -- the second command listed under the `capacity` line.

Comment: On XP I had to query "memlogical", and get the "TotalPhysicalMemory" value. "memorychip" doesn't seem to exist on XP.

Answer (score 6):

`systeminfo /s:hostname` will give you some basic memory statics if WMI isn't available on a remote machine:

```
C:\>systeminfo /s:hostname

...

Total Physical Memory:     3,062 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,116 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  2,048 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 1,996 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    52 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
```

Comment: does this really work if wmi is non functional on the remote device?

Comment: If I stop the Windows Management Instrumentation service on my Windows XP machine I can still run systeminfo against it successfully. Perhaps my test isn't good enough?

Answer (score 4):

To limit it to the Total Physical Memory and Available memory, you may use:

```
systeminfo /s:hostname | findstr "Physical"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to PowerShell (it only needs to be installed on a single workstation to run this from) you can do something like:

```
$computer = ComputerNameGoesHere
get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -computer $computer | 
select @{name="TotalPhysicalMemory(MB)";expression={($_.TotalPhysicalMemory/1mb)}}
```

You would need to either run the script as someone that can run WMI queries on remote machines (usually administrator) or work `Get-Credential` and `-credential` in there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple one:

run command line as administrative account (if in a domain)

```
SYSTEMINFO /S computername
```

There's all kinds of info including "Total Physical Memory:"

If you need to specify the user:

```
SYSTEMINFO /S system /U user
```

Answer (score 1):

`tasklist /s <system> /u <username> /p <password>` for current usage
`systeminfo /s <system> /u <username> /p <password>` for specs on system including ram.